# Theme not falling back

Tags: theme-fallback, magento-1.9.2.0

I have a website and I want to have my custom theme based on a previously installed theme which is a third party theme.

Previously installed theme is `ABC`.( set under `Theme -> Default`)

Now I have created my custom theme based on 
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/RWD_dev-guide.html
http://alanstorm.com/magento_parent_child_themes 
But the theme is not falling back to `ABC` and trying to find files in my custom theme and if it is not able to find the file in custom theme it is giving 404 error for that file.

**app/design/frontend/rwd/custom/etc/theme.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<theme>
    <parent>rwd/ABC</parent>
</theme>
```

Directory path for parent theme :
`app/design/frontend/rwd/ABC`

```
skin/frontend/rwd/ABC
```

My custom theme skin directory :

```
skin/frontend/rwd/custom
```

Please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. 
Issues are due to wrong coding standards were used. 
**There are many things in code which are hardcoded and prevented theme fallback functionality to happen.**

Answer (score 1):

In app/design/frontend/mycustomtheme/default/etc/theme.xml you need something like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<theme>
<parent>default/ABC</parent>
<layout>
    <updates>
    </updates>
</layout>
</theme>
```

Then copy/create your layout and template changes in

app/design/frontend/mycustomtheme/default/layout
app/design/frontend/mycustomtheme/default/template

If it still doesn't work, install the Alan Storm demo and modify this to point to your Parent theme.